# int divided by unsigned int causing rollover

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I try to divide int by unsigned int and I get unexpected result:

```c
int b;
unsigned int c;
int res;
float res_f;

b = -25;
c = 5;

res = b / c;   // res = 858993454
res_f = b / c; // res_f = -5.000000
```

The same works just fine for '+', '-' and '*', but fails for '/'. What is it that I miss here?

P.S.

It was tested on different compilers and the result was the same.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming this is C or similar (e.g. Objective C), change:

```
res = b / c;
```

to:

```
res = b / (int)c;
```

Explanation: b is being converted from `int` to `unsigned int`, according to C's type conversion rules for mixed expressions. In the process it overflows from `-25` to `0xFFFFFFE7 == 4294967271`. Then you get an `unsigned int` result of `4294967271 / 5U = 858993454U`, which is then being implicitly converted back to an `int` (no overflow in this step, as the result is in the range of both signed and unsigned 32-bit ints).

By the way, the `float` result should be the same, within the precision limits of a `float` (I get `858993472.0`). I'm surprised that you get -5.0 in this case.

Comment: This is why languages with implicit type conversions are evil. If you don't want crap like this happening to you, use a language with a real strong type system, like Ada.

Comment: Making `c` an `unsigned short` also works if that makes more sense in context.