# C++: Division by vector.size() gives strange results

Tags: c++, vector, std, division, integer-division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [int divided by unsigned int causing rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328269/int-divided-by-unsigned-int-causing-rollover)

Hi I am doing the following:

```
struct coord{
    int col;

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    coord c;
    c.col = 0; 

    std::vector<coord> v;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        v.push_back(coord());
    }

    c.col += -13;


    cout << " c.col is " << c.col << endl;
    cout << " v size is " << v.size() << endl;

    c.col /= v.size();


    cout << c.col << endl;

}
```

and I get the following output:

```
 c.col is -13
 v size is 5
858993456
```

However, if I change the division line to `c.col /= ((int)v.size());` I get the expected output:

```
 c.col is -13
 v size is 5
-2
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

This is a consequence of `v.size()` being `unsigned`.

See [int divided by unsigned int causing rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328269/int-divided-by-unsigned-int-causing-rollover)

Comment: so the standard way of doing this is c.col /= (int)v.size(). Is there no method on vector that returns a signed integer size?

Comment: @Aly: I think the explicit cast is the way to go.

Comment: Better to cast the numerator up to a `size_t` though, rather than narrowing the denominator by casting it to `int`.

Comment: @PaulR: But aren't we specifically talking about the case when the numerator is negative? That's when the problem arises.

Comment: @NPE: oops - my bad - in that case I'm not sure what the "best" solution is - I'm not 100% comfortable with truncating the denominator to an int though.

Comment: @PaulR: you can convert it to `ssize_t` or `intmax_t`. In theory that's a narrowing conversion. In practice it's unlikely that implementations can create a vector bigger than `SSIZE_MAX`, and impossible when `sizeof(value_type)` is bigger than `SIZE_MAX / SSIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @Steve: yes, that's just narrowing by 1 bit effectively, and as you say, 2^63 elements out to be enough for anybody.

Comment: @PaulR: just had a thought, I'll post some code that does it safely.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `vector< ... >::size()` returns `size_t`, which is a `typedef` for an `unigned` integer type. Obviously the problem arises when you divide a signed integer with an unsigned one.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector::size returns a size_t which is an unsigned integer type, usually **unsigned int**. When you perform an arithmetic operation with an **int** and an **unsigned int**, the **int** operand is converted to **unsigned int** to perform the operation. In this case, -13 is converted to **unsigned int**, which is some number close to 4294967295 (FFFFFFFF in hexadecimal). And then that is divided by 5.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the reason is that a signed / unsigned division is performed by first converting the signed value to unsigned.

So, you need to prevent this by manually converting the unsigned value to a signed type.

There's a risk that `v.size()` could be too big for an `int`. But since the dividend *does* fit in an `int`, the result of the division is fairly boring when the divisor is bigger than that. So assuming 2's complement and no padding bits:

```
if (v.size() <= INT_MAX) {
    c.col /= int(v.size());
} else if (c.col == INT_MIN && v.size() - 1 == INT_MAX) {
    c.col = -1;
} else {
    c.col = (-1 / 2);
}
```

In C++03, it's implementation-defined whether a negative value divided by a larger positive value is 0 or -1, hence the funny `(-1 / 2)`. In C++11 you can just use 0.

To cover other representations than 2's complement you need to deal with the special cases differently.